# Amazon Kindle Fire AVD

Tags: android, emulation, android-virtual-device, kindle-fire

How do I get Amazon Kindle Fire Emulator, Device definitions, and all necessary packages, etc, to emulate an Amazon device?

I have tried to get it using Android SDK Manager - links were added, but in Extras I see only Amazon Fire Phone Build Tools, Kindle Fire USB Driver, Amazon Maps API v2, but no Amazon AVD Launcher, and nothing like this: (Picture) https://www.dropbox.com/s/6f2pxlc541e9u4k/sdkMgrInstallWindow1.png?dl=0

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Kindle Fire emulators have been discontinued and no longer available to download](https://forums.developer.amazon.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=9933&tstart=0).

Instead, you can create a virtual device with the same specifications as a Fire tablet or phone. See their official guide on [Testing without an Amazon Device](https://developer.amazon.com/public/resources/development-tools/ide-tools/tech-docs/testing-without-an-amazon-device).

Comment: I've tried create virtual device with specifications as a Fire table. Is there any way to get the correct skin of GUI like is in Fire tablets? And how can I run App with amazon mapview in emulator? Please help me. Thanks many times for your suggestions.

Comment: @HSSDevelopers, the GUI is part of Amazon's FireOS. It is not available in a standard Android emulator

Comment: As for Amazon Maps API v2, it is only [compatible with FireOS 4.5.1 and higher](https://developer.amazon.com/public/apis/experience/maps/doc/faq), so you won't be able to test it with an Android emulator

Comment: You mentioned about AmazonPlatform.apk and homesimulator.apk. They are [API Simulator Tool](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/devices/fire-phone/docs/using-the-api-simulator-tool) for testing APIs from the Fire Phone SDK, e.g. side panels and app widgets. They are not related to Amazon Maps API

Answer (score 2):

You could try creating a android virtual machine that has the same specs as the Kindle Fire(Just look up the specs) to get a feel for how your app might perform on one. I think that's about all you can do, since Amazon ended its support for the Kindle emulator.

[Emulator for Amazon Kindle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7703055/emulator-for-amazon-kindle)

[Kindle Fire Emulator no longer supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23758062/kindle-fire-emulator-no-longer-supported/24285802#24285802)

Answer (score 1):

In the SDK Manager go to Tools->Manage Add-on Sites->User Defined Sites
Then, add the Amazon sites:
https://s3.amazonaws.com/android-sdk-manager/redist/addon.xml

Was that what you meant by 'links were added'?

See here for more info and links to download the SDK contents directly without using the SDK manager:
https://developer.amazon.com/appsandservices/resources/development-tools/ide-tools/tech-docs/01-setting-up-your-development-environment

Comment: Thanks a lot for you suggestion! It look this is the right way to achieve my goal. Tomorrow I'll try this way and then I say if it works. Once again, thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: I have downloaded SDK Contents from amazon website but dontknow how to open app with amazon maps api v2. I installed AmazonPlatform.apk and homesimulator.apk to avd but it is not working. Do I need to install any other apks, or setup something similar? Thanks a lot for your replies!

Comment: It also looks like the Tablets SDK link goes to the phone SDK, so unfortunately it may no longer be possible to get the old device AVD images.  Amazon just isn't supporting that line of testing anymore.